# In R , parse matrix find equal adjacent matrix and make them to zero

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

lets assume my matrix is

```
          matrix(  c(**2,2,2**,8,**2**,0,7,2,3) )
```

I need output as

```
         matrix(  c(2,**0**,2,8,2,0,7,2,3) )
```

I was trying something. sample code:

```
     initialize matrix
     A = matrix(  c(2,2,2,8,2,0,7,2,3), nrow=3,ncol=3, byrow = TRUE) 

     parsing matrix  

     for(i in 1:dim(A)[1]) 
       {
          for(j in 1:dim(A)[2]) 
             {
               checking adjacent  
                if (A[i]==A[i+1] & A[i]==A[j+1] )
                       {
                         A[i]=0
                       }
            }
      }
```

Comment: Should your example data be `A = matrix(  c(2,2,2,8,2,0,7,2,3), nrow=3,ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)`? I think you have included your output in the example code instead of your input.

Comment: yeah. you are right.

Comment: any thoughts? can u help ?